# 500 error happen in ASP.NET MVC site when submit the google recaptcha code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, recaptcha

I use google recaptcha plug-in for ASP.NET in my asp.net mvc site. It works fine when I run it from my local work station. But it is wired after I deploy it on the serve, it could load correctly but page will return 500 internal error when I submit the page with the recaptcha code. If I just leave it blank and submit the page, no error at all. 
So, I think it may be brought by some connection issue between google service?
do anyone have some idea about the issue and have any resolution?

the code is quite simple, just set public/private keys in the web.config and use HTML.RAW(recaptcha.generator...) to render the component in the page.

The code is simple: in the view, just add

```
@Html.Raw(Html.GenerateCaptcha("captcha", "clean"))
```

And in the controller, just use

```
[HttpPost] 
[RecaptchaControlMvc.CaptchaValidator] 
public ActionResult ActionName(Model model, bool captchaValid)
{
    if(captchaValid)
    {
        ModelState.AddErro("....");
    }
}
```

web.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ReCaptchaPrivateKey" value="**************" />
    <add key="ReCaptchaPublicKey" value="***************" />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: You need to give more info since it's not posible to give a diagnostic in the current form of the question. HTTP 500 is just generic code for error. What is the message included in this error? Also what is the code in the View and the Controller?

Comment: The code is simple: in the view, just add '@Html.Raw(Html.GenerateCaptcha("captcha", "clean"))' to render. And in the controller, just use "[HttpPost]
        [RecaptchaControlMvc.CaptchaValidator]
        public ActionResult ActionName(Model model, bool captchaValid)" to capture the result.

Comment: Then show it or nobody will be able to help you. Please also read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: That's all I know from my side. No error capture in the site code or in the server's event log, just return 500 when submit with recaptcha code. That's why I'm so confused about the issue.

Comment: Did you register the real domain, and are you using the correct keys? As noted on the reCAPTCHA site, "Your reCAPTCHA key is restricted to the specified domain".

Comment: Yes, use the real domain and set the keys. Or the recaptcha component even can not be loaded.

Comment: And no error captured by in the Applicaion_Error of the Global.asax